# ISO file for virtual box, windows 32 bit

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a 64 bit computer with windows 7 and want to run a 16 bit program. Thus, I installed virtual box to be able to do so.

How do I get the ISO file so that I can run e.g. windows xp in 32 bit? And does it cost money?

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) - why not just run the 32-bit program in the 64-bit OS?

Comment: 64 bit Windows runs 32 bit applications unmodified and without any need for compatibility mode, virtualization, etc. There's is no need to go through all of this to run a 32 bit application. Just double click and run.

Comment: Thank you @Tetsujin. Seems like I have misunderstood something. The program cannot run on a 64-bit OS, only on a 32-bit OS. I throught that if a program could only run on 32 bit OS then the program was also 32-bit. From reading the link posted below, and your answers, I understand it as the program is probably a 16 bit program since it only runs on 32 bit OS. I will immidiately change the question formulation. 

So the problem is getting a 16 bit program to run on a 64 bit OS.

Comment: if it is a DOS program, use [DOSBOX](https://www.dosbox.com/) to get it running on 64 bit windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Windows 32-bit program might run in compatibility mode on a 64-bit Windows system. E.g. see [here](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/316-compatibility-mode.html).

Another option is indeed setting up a virtual box instance, where you have to install a 32-bit Windows operating system first.

You would then be able to run the 32-bit Windows program within the virtualized 32-bit Windows operating system. This might enable software which won't run in compatibility mode, but comes with a certain performance penalty due to the virtualization overhead.

Microsoft supplies ISO files for some of its systems. There are tools to simplify the download, e.g. [here](https://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/67-microsoft-windows-iso-download-tool).

As with every license, it might cost money to buy a license key, or you might use a license key from an old, unused computer of yours.

**Update:**

One can use a 16-bit Windows as well. E.g. archiv.org carries an iso ([link](https://archive.org/details/Windows95ISO)) which can be run in VirtualBox.

For 16-bit DOS applications one can use the [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/) emulator, if needed together with FreeDOS. The gog.com company uses this (see below).

**Update:**

It seems the Unix `file` utility is able to identify the executables:

a) Colonization (DOS game)

```
marc@quadfork MINGW64 /c/Program Files (x86)/GalaxyClient/Games/Colonization/MPS/COLONIZE
$ file *.EXE
CLOSING.EXE: MS-DOS executable, MZ for MS-DOS
INSTALL.EXE: MS-DOS executable, MZ for MS-DOS, LZEXE v0.91 compressed
MAPEDIT.EXE: MS-DOS executable, MZ for MS-DOS
MPSCOPY.EXE: MS-DOS executable, MZ for MS-DOS
OPENING.EXE: MS-DOS executable, MZ for MS-DOS
VICEROY.EXE: MS-DOS executable, MZ for MS-DOS
```

b) Dungeon Keeper (DOS and Windows game)

```
marc@quadfork MINGW64 /c/Program Files (x86)/GalaxyClient/Games/Dungeon Keeper Gold
$ file *.EXE
DEEPER.EXE: MS-DOS executable, LE executable for MS-DOS, DOS4GW DOS extender
DOS4GW.EXE: MS-DOS executable, LE for MS-DOS, DOS4GW DOS extender (embedded)
KEEPER.EXE: MS-DOS executable, LE executable for MS-DOS, DOS4GW DOS extender
```

c) Dungeon Keeper 2 (Windows game)

```
marc@quadfork MINGW64 /c/Program Files (x86)/GalaxyClient/Games/Dungeon Keeper 2
$ file *.EXE
DKII.EXE:      PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
DKII_SOFT.EXE: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
```

This was used with the `file` command from an [msys2](http://www.msys2.org/) installation.

Comment: Thank you @mvw. I had misunderstood something apparent. It is a program that can run on 32 bit OS, thus, it must be a 16 bit program. So the problem is getting a 16 bit program to run on a 64 bit machine, which is why I need the virtual machine.